# Performance effect of Trigger and SP in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, triggers

I want to know the `Effect` of Performance of `Trigger` and `SP` on an `Sql Server DB`.
I know the difference between the `Trigger` and `SP`. But i am confuse about the `Performance` of Trigger. Are Triggers are `Slower` than SP? In difference articles i have studied that Triggers are also SP. So it means Triggers do not effect the `Performance`. Am i right? Can any one explain it to me.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

I can make a trigger that performs terribly, or a trigger that you would never notice. Similarly for a stored procedure. What matters is the code that you put in them.

They can serve completely different purposes. A stored procedure is used to accept input, affect data, etc. Or sometimes not (e.g. a stored procedure may not accept input or affect data). A trigger is used to ensure that, when one table has some action performed against it, that some other subsequent action is taken. An example is when a row is updated, the `LastModified` column can be updated by a trigger, without the user having to code that column into their `UPDATE`. While some of the logic that you perform in a trigger *could* be performed in a stored procedure, a trigger can be used to protect you from the case where data access can't be enforced through stored procedures. What good is a stored procedure that updates the `LastModified` column if your developers update the table directly instead of using the stored procedure?

So, in effect, your question is like: "which tastes better, a ham sandwich or a peanut butter cookie?" Depends on what you're in the mood for, right? There is no magic formula that will tell you whether one is better or faster than the other - they serve different purposes. People make similar comparison requests for views and procedures - again, they serve different purposes and there is no inherent performance advantage of one over the other.